# How to load SVM model fitted/ensembles with libsvm in R

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

how can i load a svm model thas was ensabled with [ensembleSVM](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~claesenm/ensemblesvm/index.php?page=home) that is referenced [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66190/methods-to-combine-e1071-svm-models-in-r-to-generate-a-more-complete-accura)?

I can export my fitted models in R with (e1071) to a 'libsvm' format

```
write.svm(model1, svm.file = "model1.svm")
write.svm(model2, svm.file = "model2.svm")
```

then build my ensemble ([doc](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~claesenm/ensemblesvm/index.php?page=userguide#merge-models))

```
merge-models -model1 model1.svm -model2 model2.svm -o model.ENSABLE.svm
```

The output result is in 'libsvm' file format.

Now how can I load the ensemble back into R and then predict new data with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the EnsembleSVM package. Unfortunately, the package does not have an R interface yet. Currently, your only option is to call `esvm-predict` via command line on the test data and then load the file containing the predictions (set using the `-o` flag). Note that the ensemble is not in exact libsvm format. Even though it looks similar, you cannot read an ensemble model using libsvm tools.

You can use R's [system()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) to invoke `esvm-predict` via command line. For what it's worth, interfaces to R, MATLAB and Python are under development currently. We hope to have them ready by the end of the year, along with a bunch of other goodies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and important hint with "Note that the ensemble is not in exact libsvm format. Even though it looks similar, you cannot read an ensemble model using libsvm tools." And i call it at the moment trouth R's system().

Comment: Glad you like it, I hope you get excellent results. Please feel free contact us for questions/suggestions/criticism regarding the package!